# convert subclass to real super class with high performance

Tags: java, performance, superclass

There are two classes `Base` and `A`.

```
class Base{
    protected int f1;
}
class  A extends Base{
    private int f2;
}
```

And i have an instance of A:

```
A a = new A();
```

Now, i want a `Base` instance for `a`, so:

```
Base b = a;
```

But `b` is not a simple `Base` on runtime, it's `a`!

So, i have to do this:

```
Base b = new Base();
b.f1 = this.f1;
```

So bad the practice! And it new a Base instace again.

I known than before init class A, the super class Base must inited.

So my question is:**Is there a quick way to get super instance without new?**

Just like this:

```
class  A extends Base{
    private int f2;
    public Base toSuper(){
        return super.this;// or return super
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just want a Base from A instance for serialization, bucasue f2 do not need to be serialized.

Comment: Is there a quick way to get super instance without **new**? No. You might want to add a copy-constructor in the `Base`.

Comment: The more important question is, what exactly are you looking to do? Do you want to access `A`'s instance of `f1`? You could just put a getter in `A` that returns `f1`. Instead of worrying about implementation, you first need to figure out what your requirements are.

Comment: There are ways to achieve what you want, but without knowing what exactly you want to do, its difficult to say.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ @musical_coder  I just want a `Base` from `A` instance for serialization, bucasue `f2` do not need to be serialized.

Comment: Make all field of `A` `transient` and they won't get serialized. In general, ask directly what you need and not what you think may lead to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an answer to your question ...

> Is there a quick way to get super instance without new?

There is in fact no simple way to create *any* instance without the `new` keyword. Period. (Exceptions are somewhat advanced: There is a deserialization mechanism and a cloning mechanism. But forget about them at the moment.)

Second, you have some misconceptions, I guess. You described an example, where you created an `A` instance:

```
A a = new A();
```

The `new A()` part creates the instance, and the `A a` part declares a variable of type `A`. The assignment (=) then stores the reference to the newly created instance in the variable.

The statement

```
Base b = a;
```

does not create a new instance. In fact, it simply declares a new variable (which at runtime will allocate some memory on the stack), assigning it the same reference that variable `a` contains. Result will be, that variables `a` and `b` will both refer to the same instance.

You are right, that at runtime this instance will be an `A` instance. The only difference between variables `a` and `b` will be at compile time: The compiler only allows you method calls and field accesses on variable `b` that are declared in the `Base` type.

Comment: but when you new A, the Base already be new before A. so there is not nedd to new Base again.

Comment: "There is in fact no way to create any instance without the new keyword. Period." Except for deserialization and `Unsafe`.

Comment: @maaartinus You are correct. I didn't want to complicate the things. And you forgot `clone()`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want f2 to be serialized, use the transient keyword.

```
class  A extends Base{
    private transient int f2;
}
```

f2 will no longer be serialized.

Comment: So many subclass and so many fileds, that's real a great work.

Comment: Maybe so. But it works. :) Besides, it's not my fault your design is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure about your requirement.If you want to access Base Class Methods Or Variable then you need to call it from your Class A methods with using super keyword..like

```
class Base{
protected int f1;
public   void methodBase()
{
    System.out.println("hello from Base");
}
```

}

```
class  A extends Base{
private int f2;
public   void methodA()
{
    f2 =super.f1;
    System.out.println("Hello from SubClass "+ f2);
    super.methodBase();
}
```

}

public class BasePackage {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A ob = new A();
    ob.methodA();
    System.out.println();
}
```